# How to add recipients to a calendar event using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to create a system where an administrator creates an event using said application and the following endpoint

```
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events
```

which works fine. The issue comes when users are to be invited to said event which is being done through the following endpoint

```
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events/{id}/forward
```

The request itself works fine but the end result is far from what's intended. The result of the forwarding requests can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzH6O.png) and the view when expanding the attached file can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSTpt.png). There is no way for the recipient of the forwarded event to accept the calendar event. Have I misinterpreted the endpoint specification found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-forward?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http , and if so, what should I do instead? I've previously attempted updating the event using PATCH to the following endpoint

```
PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events/{id}
```

But it forces you to fetch and/or cache the attendant property as it overwrites on PATCH. Any help is once more appreciated.

Comment: (1) Just to isolate the issue, you can skip the Graph API aside for a while and see if you can just use the Outlook/no code, try the above use case and see what result/observe the results. Do you see any difference?

Comment: (2) Do you use M365 account or outlook/hotmail? If you're using Outlook email, then you need to understand that if the meeting event is forwarded from an attendee's Microsoft 365 mailbox to another recipient, this action also sends a message to notify the organizer of the forwarding, and adds the recipient to the organizer's copy of the meeting event. This convenience is not available when forwarding from an Outlook.com account and [it's in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-forward?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).